# reading secular lecture or knowledge

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, books-generally

Is one allowed to read secular lecture/ knowledge (i.e. *technology, science* or *history* etc.) for pleasure reading?

1. Does the Torah or halacha explicitly tell us what one should distance himself from reading?